# Error while running sudo apt-get upgrade command

Tags: raspbian

pi@rpi-cseye:~ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Did your 'sudo apt-get update' before?

Comment: First `sudo reboot` your system. Then run `sudo apt-get clean && apt-get update`, after that, run again `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by MadAntrax, reboot your Pi and then run the command again. This is a somewhat common hiccup, either a previous apt-get command stalled and hasn't released the directory, or another process is running an update command.
`sudo reboot` or `sudo shutdown -r now`
Then `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried updating your RPI?
If not:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Welcome Kyle, but re-stating something that has been mentioned two or three times already by others is just clutter.